# how add data to json files with discord js

Tags: javascript, json, discord, discord.js, fs

Hi I try to make sure that as soon as my discord bot joins a server it writes the es of the server in the JSON file and then the first channel of the discord server below but it does not work.

```
client.on("guildCreate", (guild) => { // This event triggers when the bot joins a guild. 
    let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('guilds.json');
    let guilds = JSON.parse(rawdata);
    console.log(`Joined new guild: ${guild.name}`);
    var chx = guild.channels.cache.filter(chx => chx.type === "text").find(x => x.position === 0);
    client.newGuild [chx.guild.id] = {
        MemberAdd: chx.id,
        MemberRemove: chx.id
    }
    fs.writeFile("./guilds.json", JSON.stringify (client.newGuild, null, 4), err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Server succefull add')
    })
});
```

I get this error
[image]

I try to do this:

```
{
    "801502579829112852":{
       "MemberAdd":"801514313340289034",
       "MemberRemove":"802125586923257886"
    },
    "802163006698946570":{
       "MemberAdd":"802163007173951521",
       "MemberRemove":"802163007173951521"
    }
 }
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: In what way does it not work? What goes wrong?

Comment: @VeryGoodDog look the edit

Comment: What gives `console.log(chx.id)` ? because my guess is that var `chx = guild.channels` and not `guild` so maybe `chx.id` is `undefined`

Comment: @nazimboudeffa this gives me the server id

Comment: send me the initial content of your `guilds.json`

Comment: @justcodin in my JSON file there is this ```{}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this one :

```js
    guilds.newGuild [chx.guild.id] = {
        MemberAdd: chx.id,
        MemberRemove: chx.id
    }
    fs.writeFile("./guilds.json", JSON.stringify (guilds, null, 2), err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Server successfully add')
    })
```

plus replace your `guilds.json` with :

```json
{"newGuild":{}}
```